# How to represent irrational numbers in c++

Tags: c++

I want to represent all irrational numbers with a class in C++.

How can I do that? What suppose to be my data members and functions?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you mean rational numbers? There are an uncountable number of irrational numbers, so you need some finite approximation. `double` is one such.

Comment: No I mean, I want to calculate all  Irrational numbers in a class, with some data members like double or int.. The irrational numbers are for example pi or i.

Comment: And I want to decide if a number is an  irrational number or not. Is it possible

Comment: The definition of irrational numbers is that they can't be represented in IEEE 754 format. (Well, that's not exactly the definition but it's close enough as far as your computer is concerned.) Also, there are an infinite number of them, so you cannot possibly represent all of them. You want a finite subset, like, maybe, the named ones.

Comment: i is rational (but imaginary). What exactly do you want to be able to do with an object of this class?

Comment: And as @AlanStokes says, irrational is not the same as imaginary. It's perfectly possible to represent imaginary numbers in a class with two `double` members.

Comment: @AlanStokes lets suppose  I have a class named IrrationalNumbers. And I have a member function that decides if a number is irrational or not. How can I implement the function and these class. What suppose to be the data members?

Comment: by the way sorry I was trying to say pi and e.

Comment: Computers are finite; they can't exactly represent any irrational number. How would you pass an irrational number to the class to test it? All `double` values are rational.

Comment: For example: the square root of 2 is famously irrational. The closest `double` to it is 1.4142135623730950488 - but that is a rational number which merely approximates the true value.

Comment: @nicomp There are no units in which both diameter and circumference of a circle can be exactly measured. If there were pi could be expressed as a ratio, which would make it rational. By definition an irrational number cannot be a ratio of two (rational) numbers.

Comment: Just because you can't represent an irrational number as a double, doesn't mean you can't represent it exactly in a computer.  You can't represent all *rationals* exactly in a double, but it's really easy to write a Rational class which represents them as the ratio of two (big) integers.  For algebraic numbers (like root 2) you can do something similar (represent them as the rational polynomial of which they are the root, with a vector of (big) integers).

Comment: When you say "you want to decide if a number is irrational or not".  How will you receive this number?  If it is as a string of digits, the answer is always "not" (the whole point of irrationals is that they cannot be represented by a finite string of digits).

Comment: Thank all of you guys. I am agree with you, it is impossible to represent irrational numbers with a class in c++.

Comment: When doing calculations of sinusoidal functions, physics equations etc. that involve the use of PI in pure mathematics is in fact Irrational. When implementing PI as a real world object in computer programming, even PI is approximated. I work with 3D Graphics, Animation and Physics Simulations. What you are asking for is not feasible with our current machines! In fact PI is Irrational in Theory and supported by postulates. Even humans can not count every decimal of PI, therefor we assume that is Irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I think that you may be able to achieve something of this nature would be with identifiers and not the actual mathematical or number representations. Even in pure mathematics Irrational numbers are labeled as irrational due to given postulates. Even a human can not truly represent an irrational number by its digits. So the only thing I can suggest is to have an identifier of the known irrational numbers such as something like this:

```
enum Irrational {
    PI = 0,
    E,
    SQRT2,

    ...

};
```

Then you might want to make an association of them with a map like this:

```
std::map<Irrational, double> myIrrationals;
myIrrations.insert( std::make_pair<Irrational, double>( PI, 3.141592654 ) );
```

Then your check for irrational numbers would be true if they are found in this map and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot represent irrational numbers even in the pure math, except symbolically (like Pi, sqrt(2) - you can say "Pi" but you cannot write its exact value on the paper). And the same applies to the computer representation - if you want to represent them exactly, you cannot represent them as a "real" numbers, only symbolically (in the computer it is actually difficult to represent even the rational numbers precisely).

So, to answer your question - as a consequence of the above, your data members could be for example strings (symbols or entire expressions represented as strings, like "Pi" or "sqrt(2)") and/or combined with expression trees (operators and operands to store the expressions which represent the irrational numbers, like operator=sqrt, operand=2 and alike).